# Resolve Gradle Transitive Dependency Conflict with file system libs (ie. not maven, ivy)

Tags: gradle

We have a java project with dependencies that looks something like this.

```
A -> B -> httpcore-4.0.1
\         
 C -> httpcore-4.1.3
```

So there is transitive dependency conflict in A. The gradle docs say that the resolution policy is to select the newest (http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html). However, we get compile errors due to function signature differences so the latest doesn't seem to be selected. I've seen various exclude methods but not sure how they apply when we are using a file system based dependency lib (not maven or ivy). Eclipse seems to resolve the problem okay and compile but gradle barfs. I've tried various forms of:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group:'org.apache', name: 'httpcore', version:'4.0.1'
    all*.exclude group:'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version:'4.0.1'
}
```

What am I missing here?

I'm using Gradle 1.0-milestone-8a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just not done. See http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/resolve_gradle_transitive_dependency_conflict_with_file_system_libs_ie_not_maven_ivy

You have to use a local or remote repos.